# how does the addition of 1×1 layers reduce from the complexity and solve sparse structure in inception module?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, computer-vision

Based on the ([going deeper with convolutions](https://www.cs.unc.edu/~wliu/papers/GoogLeNet.pdf)) paper. The ***inception module*** consists of multiple branches, each branch consists of convolution layer and each layer has a different kernel size for example (1×1, 3×3, 5×5).
The benefit of this model is to make your model choose the beast feature maps from these branches by concatenating them before next layer.

The problem with it the expensive computation because of the (3×3, 5×5) layers and might cover the optimal sparse structure issue. So they add before each layer the (1×1) conv layer to solve these two problems.

my question is::
How does the (1×1) conv layer reduce from the complexity and solve sparse structure issue???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine you have an input tensor of size `(32,32,512)` where the dimensions correspond to `(Height,Width,Channels)` and imagine you have to apply a `128` different `5x5` convolutions to this tensor. This means you will need `128` filters of size `(5,5,512)` which is quite a lot of computation. Each filter needs to have a depth of `512` in order to account for the depth of the input tensor.

Now, instead of applying `5x5` convolutions directly, you apply `128` different `1x1` convolutions first. To do this you will need `128` filters of size `(1,1,512)` which is **much less** (about 25 times less) computation than applying `128` `5x5` filters. This is because to do a `5x5` filter, you have to take `25*512` multiplications and add them together at each step, while to do a `1x1` filter you only do `512` multiplications at each step. After you passed the `1x1` convolutions you are left with a tensor of shape `(32,32,128)` which you can then pass onto the `5x5` convolutions. Having reduced the depth of the tensor from `512` to `128` your `5x5` convolutions will have much less work to do.

The net effect of the `1x1` convolutions is if you took each pixel in your input tensor and ran them through a (shared) 1 layer neural network to reduce their size. In the example above, regard each pixel of the input tensor as a `512` dimensional input to a fully connected neural network a `128` dimensional output. That's essentially what the `1x1` convolutions are doing. If your tensors have become so deep that they are unweildy (as happens in inception), then it might make sense to use `1x1` convlutions to reduce the depth of the tensors before applying larger convolutions.