# What is the purpose or benefits of fully connected layer at the middle of Convolutional Network?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow, caffe

Is there any benefits to have FC layer at the middle of CNN network?

For example, in this [network](https://github.com/intel/caffe/blob/master/models/intel_optimized_models/ssd/VGGNet/coco/SSD_300x300/train.prototxt), FC7 has kernel size is 1. What is the benefits of using kernel size 1 in this use?

Those inception net, kernel size 1 is used for lower down the computation.

Is that same purpose or for different advantages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A kernel size of 1 does not make it a fully connected layer. This type of layer is called a 1x1 convolution (or "network-in-network") layer. As you noted, this is often used to reduce computational costs.

There are a few other questions and answers on this site regarding the purpose of this type of layer:

[What does 1x1 convolution mean in a neural network?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/194142/what-does-1x1-convolution-mean-in-a-neural-network)

[how does the addition of 1×1 layers reduce from the complexity and solve sparse structure in inception module?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/352763/how-does-the-addition-of-1%C3%971-layers-reduce-from-the-complexity-and-solve-sparse)